# Threat modelling workshop materials focusing on threat actor profiles

Tags: threat-modeling, vulnerability-assessment

A while back I went to a threat modelling workshop that had a card deck with  various actors, their motivations, and their methods.

I found this extremely helpful to frame the discussion around the probability / motivation for an attack to occur, in a way that neither OWASP Cornucopia neither "Elevation of Privilege" do -- they focus heavily on the technical execution of attacks.

**What are the best threat modelling materials you have the focus not only on the technical execution of an attack, but also consider the context and motivation for it?**

What was used in the workshop looked something like:

```
Script Kiddie

A lower skilled actor, using mostly preexisting tools 
to exploit known vulnerabilities. Mostly motivated though fame 
and recognition from their peers.

Skill level: Low
Main motivation: Recognition
Resources: Low
```

Or

```
State actor

Heavily funded, and with virtually unlimited resources. Mostly
motivated to gather intel on other big actors, looking for leverage
into other states' industry, infrastructure and sovereignty 

Skill level: High
Main motivation: Interference with other state actors
Resources: High
```

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find a product or service that does X?" are off-topic as the potential answers will not end. The list of threat actors, though are pretty static (and small) and you can find these lists online.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those are actual threat actors, not threat actor profiles, and this is more of a discussion about workshop materials that focus on context of risk assessment. I can rephrase it a but I still find this relevant for the community

Comment: No, I'm talking about threat actor profiles. There are many preconfigured sets.

Comment: Change your search queries to "threat actor categories". I think you are getting the "profiles" of specific threat actors. There have been sets of what you are looking for for years. I've never seen a list longer than 10.

Comment: Looking for resources that exist out in the public is generally a poor-fitting question on QA sites such as this. If there is one definitive source that can be cited, that is wholly authoritative, and is expected to be public for a very long time (such as RFCs or NIST standards, etc.), then good. However, for something like characterizing threat actors, where there isn't one authoritative source, sources may go offline or restructure their site over the years, and the list of threat actors itself is unlikely to change much, it's best to ask for the threat actors here, rather than resources.